# why "java -version" may crash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

On Ubuntu Linux 10.10 (and I had the same problem on 10.04) java (from openjdk-6-jre-headless) crashes for unknown reason:

```
me@ub:~$ java -version 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 304 bytes for CHeapObj-new. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:39), pid=14459, tid=140557172041488
#  Error: CHeapObj-new
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b20
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (17.0-b16 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.9.1
# Distribution: Ubuntu 10.10, package 6b20-1.9.1-1ubuntu3
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/me/hs_err_pid14459.log
```

There is a lot of free memory, so that's not the cause.  If I log in as another user, it works:

```
guests@ub:~$ java -version 
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.1) (6b20-1.9.1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

So the crash seems to be caused by some local changes that I made.

- Both users have no JAVA* env vars set.
- The crash does not depend on the current working directory.
- According to strace, no files in the home directory are opened.

I have no idea what can be the reason. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might get better answers at @ [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com)

Comment: Sathya: Thanks! I didn't know about AskUbuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by my settings in /etc/security/limits.conf where I set "address space limit" to 1GB. For some reason java needs more than 1GB of virtual memory to start:

```
wojdyr@ub:~$ java -version 
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.1) (6b20-1.9.1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
wojdyr@ub:~$ ulimit -Sv 1048576
wojdyr@ub:~$ java -version 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 304 bytes for CHeapObj-new. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:39), pid=3319, tid=140563844388624
#  Error: CHeapObj-new
```

I don't understand why so much memory is needed. All other programs I use work fine with 1GB limit. Anyway, the problem is solved.